# tmux not respecting disabled control flow

Tags: terminal, keyboard, tmux

In my shell I have flow control disabled using `stty -ixon`. This works
perfectly in the shell and when I launch `tmux` and start programs within
`tmux`.

However, when starting a new session from the command line and directly
launching a command, the flow control setting is not respected and
<kbd>ctrl-s</kbd> freezes the terminal.

This works:

```
tmux new-session -s foo
vim
```

This does not respect the `stty` flow control setting:

```
tmux new-session -s foo vim
```

How can I disable flow control even in the latter case?

Comment: Is it sufficient to disable flow control all together within `tmux` for all cases, or are you interested in nailing down why it works in the first example but not the second?

Comment: @slm In the first place I'd like to have it fixed. Nevertheless, I'm interested why tmux behaves as it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have `stty -ixon` in your shell's initialization, it's rather simple: when `tmux` creates new terminals, it runs user's default shell by default and that in turn disables the control flow during the initialization. However, when you ask tmux to run a specific command (ViM in your case), no initialization takes place and the default terminal settings (flow control enabled) apply.

```
tmux new-session -s foo "stty -ixon; vim"
```

should fix your problem.

Answer (score 6):

A workaround which does not require changing the `tmux` call is to include the `stty` call in the file `$HOME/.zshenv`. This file is parsed by ZSH  and used even for non-interactive shells.

```
echo 'stty -ixon' | tee -a ~/.zshenv
# ... or ...
echo 'stty -ixon' >> ~/.zshenv
```

BASH users have to set the environment variable `BASH_ENV=$HOME/.zshenv` to make this work.

Comment: I don't know what it does, but it did the trick. Added it to both `.zshrc` and `.zshenv`. Be careful with `>` though. Use: `echo 'stty -ixon' >> ~/.zshenv`